# How to find the length or size of the elements of response array in rest assured

Tags: java, api, rest-assured

I am new to rest assured. I have tried below code for getting response

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8090/api";
Response resp = 
          given().
          when().get("/modules")
         .then().extract().response();
```

This is JSON response

```
    [
        {
            "moduleid": "1000",
            "module": "reader",
            "title": "Learn to read",
            "description": "Learn to read and understand code"
        },
       {
        "moduleid": "1005",
        "module": "debug",
        "title": "Can you fix it?",
        "description": "Learn how to uncover logical mistakes"
       },
    ]
```

How do I get the **length or size** of the elements of that array.

Comment: Do you expect to see `2` in your example?

Comment: No, that would be the length of the response array right!

Comment: What is length or response array? What value do you expect for your sample response?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I expect the value of 4 as I want to know the size of `{
        "moduleid": "1005",
        "module": "debug",
        "title": "Can you fix it?",
        "description": "Learn how to uncover logical mistakes"
       }`

Comment: I mean if there is a way to find

Comment: There is the way. So you mention `"moduleid": "1005"` but not `"moduleid": "1000"`. Do you want to have the way to specify the particular item in response?

Comment: _moduleid_ can be random, I just gave an example and as for _Do you want to have the way to specify the particular item in response?_ YES

Comment: @suhelshaikh The `length` you mean is the number of key-value pair of the json object?

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 yes exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above comment, the `length` here is the number of key-value pair in the json object.

For me, you can choose any object in the array to count the number of key-value pair, but if you want to specify the json object with condition, for example `moduleid=1005`, this code would work for you.

```
Map<String, Object> parsed = resp.jsonPath().get("find {it.moduleid = '1005'}");
int numberOfPair = parsed.keySet().size();
System.out.println(numberOfPair); //4
```

Comment: @suhelshaikh please mark it correct answer if it solves your problem, thanks

Comment: Your solution is correct. Returns me the output I want the size of 4

Answer (score 1):

Since the response document does not tell you the amount of elements (and we are not sure whether the server returns a correct `content-size` header, you will have to parse the response and count.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://demo1954881.mockable.io";
    Response resp =
            given().
                    when().get("/modules")
                    .then().extract().response();

    ArrayList<Map> parsed = resp.jsonPath().get();
    List<Map> result = parsed
            .stream()
            .filter(i -> "1000".equals(i.get("moduleid")))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    result.forEach(
            map -> System
                    .out
                    .printf(
                       "Item with [moduleid=%s] has size of %d\n",
                       map.get("moduleid"), map.size())
    );
}
```

Since you are ware of the response structure it is a simple array of maps. So you serialize it into array of maps and then use regular toolset for manipulating with data.